# php XLSXWriter - links only appearing sometimes?

Tags: php, xlsx

I am working with XLSXWriter - https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter

When I am creating links, I am writing it like:
`=HYPERLINK("%s", "%s")',$url,$value`

When I view the resulting file in google sheets, I get a wee link like this:
[A cell containing the letter A, it is underlined and blue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IEHo.png)

Explicitly a link, blue underline, I didn't have to do any styling to get it looking like this.

However, in excel and libreoffice, This just looks like text.
I can control click it and it works like a link, the cell value has the hyperlink format in it, but it just looks like a regular letter in the cell.
[Regular letter A - no format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o5b1.png)

Is there a parameter I'm missing? a style I need to apply? This is an issue that others are seeing when they download this xlsx file - it needs to be obvious it is a link to the users. What am I missing to make this link explicit always, not sometimes?